# Compatibility of Lenovo with Ubuntu

Tags: lenovo

Could you please tell me if my machine is compatible with Ubuntu 22.04 based on the specifications below?

Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-1260P
RAM: 16 GB LPDDR5-5200MHz
Storage: 512 GB SSD
Graphics Card: Intel Iris Xe Graphics
System type: 64-bit, x64

If you need any additional information, I'd be happy to let you know.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Sincerely,
Bryan

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Would you add the model? people who have same one may give best feedback. Just a hint, when looking for new hardware support,  check https://ubuntu.com/certified and https://linux-hardware.org/ for same model or similar parts/devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) and [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/986878/)

Answer (score 0):

it's a 64 bit computer with 512gb of space and 16gb of ram, any *unix os will work with that, ubuntu especially, you have enough space to install apps and 16gb of ram is plenty for ubuntu

Comment: Download the latest Ubuntu LTS release, burn it to a USB disk. When you boot from it, use the "Try Ubuntu" mode. It won't touch your hard disk.